# Translate specific columns to rows

Tags: linux, awk

I have this file (space delimited) :

```
bc1 no 12
bc1 no 15
bc1 yes 4
bc2 no 8  
bc3 yes 14 
bc3 yes 12
bc4 no 2
```

I would like to get this output :

```
bc1 3 no;no;yes 31
bc2 1 no 8
bc3 2 yes;yes 26
bc4 1 no 2
```

1st column : one occurence of the first column in the input file

2nd : number of this occurence in the input file

3rd : 3rd column translated in row with ";" delimiter

4th : sum of the last column

I can do what I want with the "no/yes" column :

```
awk -F' ' 'NF>2{a[$1] = a[$1]";"$2}END{for(i in a){print i" "a[i]}}' test.txt | sort -k1,1n
```

Comment: Is the input always sorted on first column? Also, please add what you've tried?

Comment: The first column is always sorted right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One alternative `awk` idea:

```
awk '
function print_row() {
    if (series)
       print key,c,series,sum
    c=sum=0
    series=sep=""
}
    { if ($1 != key)                # if 1st column has changed then print previous data set
         print_row()
      key=$1
      c++
      series=series sep $2
      sep=";"
      sum+=$3
    }
END { print_row() }                 # flush last data set to stdout
' input
```

This generates:

```
bc1 3 no;no;yes 31
bc2 1 no 8
bc3 2 yes;yes 26
bc4 1 no 2
```

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code. Since $1(first column) is always sorted we need not to sort it so coming up with this solution here.

```bash
awk '
prev!=$1 && prev{
  print prev OFS count,value,sum
  count=sum=0
  prev=value=""
}
{
  prev=$1
  value=(value?value ";":"") $2
  count++
  sum+=$NF
}
END{
  if(prev){
     print prev OFS count,value,sum
  }
}
'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution with newer versions of [datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/) (thanks [glenn jackman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7552/glenn-jackman) for the tips about `count` and `--collapse-delimiter`):

```bash
datamash -t' ' -g1 --collapse-delimiter=';' count 2 collapse 2 sum 3 <ip.txt
```

With older versions (mine is `1.4`) and `awk`:

```bash
$ datamash -t' ' -g1 count 2 collapse 2 sum 3 <ip.txt
bc1 3 no,no,yes 31
bc2 1 no 8
bc3 2 yes,yes 26
bc4 1 no 2

$ <ip.txt datamash -t' ' -g1 count 2 collapse 2 sum 3 | awk '{gsub(/,/, ";", $3)} 1'
bc1 3 no;no;yes 31
bc2 1 no 8
bc3 2 yes;yes 26
bc4 1 no 2
```

`-t` helps to set space as field separator. Column 2 is collapsed by using column 1 as the key. `sum 3` helps to find the total of the numbers. `count 2` helps to count the number of collapsed rows.

Then, `awk` is used to change the `,` in the third column to `;`

Comment: Adding `count 2` mostly removes the need for awk (except to translate commas)

Comment: version 1.8 of datamash adds `--collapse-delimiter`: `datamash -t ' ' -g 1 --collapse-delimiter=';' count 3 collapse 2 sum 3 < file`